# Bind check on column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, bind

I'm pretty new with VB & ASPX.NET.
But I'm having a problem with showing the right info in a gridview.

Basically I've got a maintenance tool for an application. And I want to make it multi language.

This is a check for the language:

```
'setting the column name where to get the text resource from
Dim comment As String = "comment"
If (licentie.getlanguage() = "NL") Then
    comment = "comment_NL"
End If

'Part of the sql query
sqlDataSourceGridView.SelectCommand = "select inst.categorie,inst.term_id,inst.term_result,inst." + comment + ", ETC.....
```

So far this works. But in my template I've got the following code in the gridview:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>' />
```

So my question is, How do I set the column 'comment_NL' when the language is set 'NL' in the bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give a **Column Alias** for `inst.comment` and `inst.comment_NL` by using `AS` in your Select Query

```
select inst.categorie,inst.term_id,inst.term_result,inst." + comment + " AS Comment, ETC.....
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
You just helped out a front-end developer in trouble! =)